# scala curried function with yield

Tags: scala, yield

I try to learn curried functions in Scala,
see the code

```
  def isEven(v: Int): Boolean = v % 2 == 0

  def evens(numbers: List[Int])(even: Int => Unit) {
    for (number <- numbers; if isEven(number)) {
      even(number)
    }
  }

  val my = List.range(1, 100)

  evens(my){println(_)} // works fine and prints the even numbers as expected 

  val recurse = evens(my) { yield _ } //compilation error
```

I would like to get the result as yield accumulation, but I can not fined how to do that in Scala documentation nor any example.
Any idea?

Comment: I don't think you can separate `yield` from the `for` part, nor I can think of any possible use case for this, the for you have in `evens` returns `Unit`, what should the `yield` do?

Comment: Yeah, `yield ...` itself is neither a statement nor an expression. It only exists as part of a `for ... yield ...` expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot abstract over the two forms of `for` usage.  One desugars to a `foreach` while the other to `map` and (possibly) `flatMap`; the return types are also different.

You can write two functions, or you can write a generic method and ignore the return value:

```
def evens[A](numbers: List[Int])(even: Int => A): List[A] = {
  for (number <- numbers if (number % 2) == 0) yield even(number)
}
```

Now if you want the list back unchanged you use the `identity` function:

```
val e = evens(my)(identity)
val e = evens(my)(x => x)   // Equivalent
```

If you want to do something to it, you ignore the return value:

```
evens(my)(println)
```

Comment: Yes it works for me, but I still do not understands the trick and why it could not be defined more elegantly.

Comment: @moshebeeri - Well, I'm not sure _which_ part you don't understand, so all I can recommend is to become more familiar with Scala.  But as to why it could not be defined more elegantly, it just has to do with how `for` was conceived.  Scala is not _just_ doing textual replacement, so you can't mix random parts of syntax--e.g. you can't do `def foo = (_ bar = 5); foo(def)` to create `def bar = 5`.  One could make different decisions in language design to allow that (and end up with something more like C macros or Lisp, depending on the details).

Comment: Considering this code
def evens(numbers: List[Int])(even: Int => Unit) {
    for (number <- numbers; if isEven(number)) {
      even(number)
    }
  }

    val f = evens(my) _
in this definition why can I call the function f.foreach{println(_)}

Answer (score 0):

Scala curried functions are not interned to be used with yield as I have tried in my question,
for that purpose there is no need to use curried functions at all as you simply ca to the following:

```
  def evens(numbers: List[Int]) : List[Int] = {
     for (number <- numbers if (number % 2) == 0) yield number
  }
```

and then:

```
    val my = List.range(1, 100)
    evens(my).foreach(f => println(f))
```

Thanks to @RexKerr for his solution showing how to utilize generics and curried functions to yield and return the curried results.