# why yield can not work with while loop in scala

Tags: scala, yield-keyword

In Scala, `yield` can work with for-loops; for example:

```
val ints: IndexedSeq[Int] = for(i <- 1 to 10) yield i
```

But I found that `yield` can not work with while-loops, e.g. like:

```
while (resultSet.next()) yield new Row(resultSet)
```

Why is Scala designed like this?

I have searched on Google and stackoverflow, but could not find an answer.

Comment: No. It cannot. `yield` is part of the `for` comprehension.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26149409/scala-curried-function-with-yield

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because a while loop is a java equivalent while loop, and the 'for loop' is translated to function call of: `<IndexedSeq>.map` (if you use yield) or `<IndexedSeq>.foreach` (if you don't care the result).

Example Scala Code:

```
class ForVsWhileLoop {
  val dummy = for(i <- 1 to 10) yield i

  var dummy2 = Seq.empty[Int]
  var i = 0
  while(i <= 10)
    dummy2 :+= i
}
```

Compiles to (scala -Xprint:parse ForVsWhileLoop.scala):

```
[[syntax trees at end of                    parser]] // ForVsWhileLoop.scala
package <empty> {
  class ForVsWhileLoop extends scala.AnyRef {
    def <init>() = {
      super.<init>();
      ()
    };

    // ***********************************************
    // the 'for loop' is translated to a function call
    val dummy = 1.to(10).map(((i) => i));


    var dummy2 = Seq.empty[Int];
    var i = 0;

    // *******************
    // classic while loop
    while$1(){
      if (i.$less$eq(10))
        {
          dummy2.$colon$plus$eq(i);
          while$1()
        }
      else
        ()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The difference lies in the interpretation of the for comprehension, which can be seen as a DSL.
If there is a **yield** the comprehension will be translated to something using **map** and **flatMap** and collect the results.
If there is no yield the expression will be translated to something using **foreach**, iterating over all values ignoring the results.

**While** on the other hand is just a function that does something until a certain condition is met and returns nothing, i.e. **Unit** at the end.
It is just called for sied effects and not for returning results. Thus even if you use **yield** the result will be thrown away.

The implemention you have given above uses the the Iterator pattern and would work exactly like **foreach** does.

**While** returns **Unit** , like **foreach** :

```
scala> val res : Unit = (1 to 10) foreach {i => i + 1}
```

whereas **for** with **yield** returns a result and behaves like map.

```
scala> val res : Seq[Int] = (1 to 10) map {i => i + 1}
res: Seq[Int] = Vector(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)

scala> val res = for (i<- 1 to 10) yield i +1 
res: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `while` works like described here: [while-loop-expressions](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#while-loop-expressions)
i.e. while loop expression returns `Unit`.

Your `yield` value is implicitly converted to this `Unit` as described here: [Implicit conversion to the Unit type in Scala](http://blog.bruchez.name/2012/10/implicit-conversion-to-unit-type-in.html) .

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what gets converted to a captured state which we can 'yield':

https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html